# <nav> and <button> are sister elements. How can I write CSS for the <button> when the <nav> active class is added?

Tags: html, css

```html
<nav class="">
    <a class="nav-item">1</a>
    <a class="nav-item">2</a>
    <a class="nav-item">3</a>
    <a class="nav-item">3</a>
    <a class="nav-item">4</a>
</nav>

<button class="mobile-button">Button</button>
```

The code above is my HTML template. If "active" is added in the `<nav>` class, I want to write CSS to the `<button>` below, how can I select this?

Please don't put the button in navigation, I need to do it this way.

Comment: Your question needs more details. I have no idea what the question is.

Comment: If nav="active", I want to write css to the <button> code below. If there is no "active" in nav="", css will not be applied.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you could use the [next sibling combinator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Next-sibling_combinator) `+` if *button* immediately follows *nav*:

```css
nav.is-active + .mobile-button {
  /* styles here */
}
```

or, if a more distant sibling, you could use the [`~` subsequent sibling combinator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Subsequent-sibling_combinator):

```css
nav.is-active ~ .mobile-button {
  /* styles here */
}
```

Using the [`:has()` pseudo-class](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:has) you could also refer to a parent having an active child and than refer to the target:

```css
body:has(nav.is-active) .mobile-button {
  /* styles here */
}
```

or just like:

```css
:has(nav.is-active) .mobile-button {
  /* styles here */
}
```